# C# Xamarin bind List to Chart

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, list, xamarin

I created a List and selected 1 Name from the List with all the Prices and Timestamps.

This is my List Class:

```
public class price
{
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public string PRICE { get; set; }
    public string TIMESTAMP { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the part where I select a few things:

```
var singleNameWithOldestPrice =
    from p in PriceList
    where p.NAME.Contains(SelectedProduct, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    group p by p.NAME into grp
    select grp.OrderBy(a => a.TIMESTAMP).ToArray();
```

Now I want to bind the PRICES to the Chart.
I use the NuGet Package: MicroCharts. This is how you create a chart with that program:

```
PriceChart.Chart = new PointChart { Entries = Source };
```

How can I use the Prices as Source?

FULL EDITED CODE:

```
var singleNameWithOldestPrice =
    from p in PriceList
    where p.NAME.Contains(SelectedProduct, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    group p by p.NAME into grp
    select grp.OrderBy(a => a.TIMESTAMP).ToArray();

var source = new List<Entry>();

foreach (var p in singleNameWithOldestPrice)
{
    source.Add(new Entry(p.PRICE)
    {
        Label = p.NAME,
        ValueLabel = p.PRICE,
        Color = Color.Red
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create an array of entries , based on your example if i well understand ,  it should be smth like this

```
var source = new List<Entry>();
foreach(var p in singleNameWithOldestPrice )
{
source.Add(new Entry(p)
{
    Label = "name of every label",
    ValueLabel = p,
    Color = Color.Red
})
}
```

Comment: It crashes on the words: "PRICE and NAME", with the error: "'IOrderedEnumerable<price>' does not contain a definition for 'PRICE' and no extension method 'PRICE' accepting a first argument of type 'IOrderedEnumerable<price>' couldn't be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

Comment: okay i get it , with your filter and search you get only list of price can you try
foreach(var p in singleNameWithOldestPrice )
{
source.Add(new Entry(p)
{
    Label = "Name",
    ValueLabel = p,
    Color = Color.Red
})
}

Comment: I get the error on both the "p": "Cannot Convert from Project.price[] to float/string"

Comment: i don't know exactly the type of singleNameWithOldestPrice  because you extract prices in groupe so i think that a grouped array ! why not use prices directly to the chart so you use them from PriceList  foreach(var p in PriceList)